# Lightroom doesn't show all known lens profiles

Tags: lens, lightroom

Only in one of my projects I have the problem that I can't choose more than one lens profile for my photos, because there's only one lens in each maker's list and the list is much shorter than usual. I shot with different lenses during that project, the problem applies to all of them. In all my other projects I can choose whichever lens profile I want. Is there a setting which filters lens profiles or anything like that?

I'm on Lightroom 5.7.1 on OS X 10.10.5.

All the problematic photos were shot in JPEG mode. Is this the cause?

SOLVED: it's because I shot in JPEG. Seems like you have to create your own profile for JPEG files.

Comment: Can you provide more info about the equipment. What lenses are you using and on what body etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Adobe says](https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/lens-profile-support.html#main_List_of_supported_lenses) that Lightroom only shows the profiles that match the camera and image type. Also JPEG files do not properly support the data that helps identify lenses:

> There are separate lens profiles for raw and non-raw files. Photoshop, Camera Raw, and Lightroom display only the profiles available for the file type of the selected image.
>
> Best results occur when you apply lens profiles to raw files.
>
> When you apply a lens profile to a non-raw file, such as a JPEG, you can experience unexpected results. Results vary because the data in non-raw files changes depending on how the file was created. If you get unexpected results with non-raw files, consider applying lens corrections manually or create a custom lens profile.

Comment: Thanks, after doing some research I found some posts on Adobe's support pages with exactly my problem.